# I cant pass my date to my sql even i set the type of my data to date?

Tags: php

```
<?php

session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect to database");
mysqli_select_db($connection, "carkila") or die("No database exist");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_account";
$user = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO user_account(Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name, User_name, Password, Birth_date, Address, Contact_no) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss",$_POST['lName'],$_POST['fName'],$_POST['mName'],$_POST['uName'],$_POST['uPassword'],$_POST['bDate'],$_POST['uAddress'],$_POST['cNumber']);

$stmt->execute();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Accounts</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "?" method = "POST">
<input type = "text" name = "lName" placeholder="Enter Last Name"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "fName" placeholder="Enter First Name"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "mName" placeholder="Enter Middle Name"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "uName" placeholder="Enter User Name"><br>
<input type = "password" name = "uPassword" placeholder="Enter Password"><br>
<input type = "date" name = "bDate" placeholder="BirthDate"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "uAddress" placeholder="Enter Address"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "cNumber" placeholder="Enter Contact Number"><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the error from passing the data of the date to my sql.
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Carkila\register.php on line 13

Comment: Remove 1 s from the bind_param()

Comment: It looks like you have 8 columns, but 9 placeholders `?` in your `->prepare()` statement. And then again in your `->bind_param()` you have 9 `s`, but only 8 parameters

Comment: LOL THANK YOU. I didn't noticed that. Thanks. Hahahaha! :D @sean

Comment: Thanks I didn't noticed that now I can work in peace. Haha! @Levi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `bind_param("sssssssss"`

to `bind_param("ssssssss"`

You current have 9 `s` where as you only have 8 parameters.

In short words, remove 1 single `s` from your bind_param()